# Is it possible to use WebAudio to process all outgoing browser audio?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to build some code to process the audio found in other pages by injecting some JavaScript into the page. I was under the impression that I could create an AudioContext and then create an onaudioprocess function, and it would be called with all outgoing audio.

```
var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var context = new AudioContext();
var proc = context.createScriptProcessor(16384, 0, 2);

proc.onaudioprocess = function (event) {
    var buffer= event.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    for( var iSample in buffer )
        if( buffer[iSample] > 0.0 )
            alert( "SDRFSDF" );
};

proc.connect(context.destination);
```

I set this up, and I never get any nonzero samples, even if I'm playing a video or some other audio source. Did I forget to hook something up? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't get access to "all outgoing audio" in a page (e.g. Flash videos) with the Web Audio API.

If there's an HTML video or audio tag on the page, you could use `AudioContext#createMediaElementSource`, assuming that the `src` of the media element was from the same origin as the page (or if the media asset was served with CORS headers).

Comment: Is there some other API that I could use?

Comment: Nope. At least nothing I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly get all the  and  element of the page, and pipe that to Web Audio, like so (building on your example):

```
var av = document.querySelectorAll('audio, video');
// for each source, connect it to the script processor node
for (var i = 0; i < av.length; i++) {
    context.createMediaElementSource(av[i]).connect(proc);
}`
```

This will only work if the source is same origin, though, or if the server answered with CORS headers. This only works if the audio and video elements are actually in the dom, though.